# how do you set the default arrangement of the screen in phonegap?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap

I want to change it from landscape to portrait.

Answer (score 0):

add in **config.xml**

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it